# iptables redirect traffic from VPN interface to next interface

Tags: iptables, vpn, openvpn

Can you help me with this problem please? I need redirect all traffic from tun0 interface (OpenVPN tunnel) to eth1 interface. eth1 is internal network behind this system which works as special firewall... If I use this rule (now only for testing purposes - destination port 80):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.199.115.146
```

traffic from VPN pass correctly. I see it in iptables statistic (iptables -L -v), but reverse traffic does not pass. iptables shows this error:

```
99689.703349 x_tables: ip_tables: tcp match: only valid for protocol 6
```

I need redirect all traffic from machine behind firewall only via tun0 interface. I use this rule too:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I have enabled `ip_forward`.
If I use rule only with `-p tcp` without `-m tcp` I see in iptables statistic activity in the rule `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE`

**interfaces**

*VPN Server (A):*

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:...
          inet addr:MY_PUBLIC_IP  Bcast:MY_PUBLIC_IP.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: .../64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: .../64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:41909528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:373639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2150448064 (2.1 GB)  TX bytes:185713075 (185.7 MB)
          Interrupt:10

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.1.1.1  P-t-P:10.1.1.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:82014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:164251 errors:0 dropped:24 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:5945388 (5.9 MB)  TX bytes:147587733 (147.5 MB)
```

**on firewall machine:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:...
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:189399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:103528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:180399131 (180.3 MB)  TX bytes:14844868 (14.8 MB)


tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.1.1.2  P-t-P:10.1.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:153314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:80986 errors:0 dropped:8 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:145341797 (145.3 MB)  TX bytes:5818996 (5.8 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:...
          inet addr:10.199.115.1  Bcast:10.199.115.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6890 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:710721 (710.7 KB)  TX bytes:43966879 (43.9 MB)
```

*machine B:*

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:...
          inet addr:10.199.115.146  Bcast:10.199.155.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: .../64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:24185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8044 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:29645960 (28.2 MiB)  TX bytes:842414 (822.6 KiB)
```

**Schema:**

`VPN server (A) /eth0 - public IP, tun0 VPN/ <-> Firewall (F) /tun0 VPN, eth1 - internal network/ <-> Server (B) (eth0 - internal network)`

Communication which is initialized from machine behind the firewall works ok. 
Thank you very much for your help.

**Routing tables:**

VPN server A: - is VPS server

```
10.1.1.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.1
MY_PUBLIC_IP.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src MY_PUBLIC_IP
10.199.115.0/24 via 10.1.1.2 dev tun0
default via MY_PUBLIC_IP.1 dev eth0  metric 100
```

*///one physical server*

Firewall F: is virtual machine VirtualBox Ubuntu
- eth0 is VirtualBox NAT, but I need use tun0 and eth1 is local network for B

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.1.1.1 dev tun0
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
10.1.1.1 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.2
10.199.115.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.199.115.1
MY_PUBLIC_IP via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.1.1.1 dev tun0
```

B machine on eth1 side (no eth0) is virtual machine Debian 7

```
default via 10.199.115.1 dev eth0 proto static
10.199.115.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.199.115.146
```

Route for packets should be as much as possible transparent even invisible...

**iptables rules:**

***on VPN Server (A):***

only table NAT:

```
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 0:1192 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.2
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1195:65535 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.2
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 0:1192 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.2
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1195:65535 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.2
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

*FILTER table*

```
is empty
```

*MANGLE table*

```
is empty
```

***on firewall (F):***

currently after last modification

*NAT table:*

```
none
```

*FILTER table*

```
contains many specific rules for mitigation etc...
```

*MANGLE table*

```
is empty
```

***on machine B***

```
without iptables rules
```

Comment: i think you need only `-p tcp` without `-m tcp`. Also, you need to enable `ip_forward`, which I guess you did

Comment: Which ip address/netmask do you have on the two interfaces `tun0` and `eth0`? Do you want machines on the `tun0` side to be able to connect to machines to the `eth0` side? Do you want the opposite? Both?

Comment: @pqnet Thanks. Yes I have enabled ip_forward and I have tried only with p, update is in my main topic. I added interfaces too... And yes, I want interconnect tun0 (it is public IP address on internet) to eth1 (it is network adapter for special server) via firewall machine...

Comment: you shouldn't need any iptables configuration if you configured the routing on the other machines correctly. Let's say `A` is a machine on the openvpn side, `F` is your firewall and `B` a machine on the `eth0` side of the firewall. As I said, you shouldn't need any particular configuration on firewall, so the problem is most likely on the other machines. Which operating system do you have on machines `A` and `B`? Do you know how to print their routing tables?

Comment: @pqnet I updated my main topic. I used ip route show.

Comment: @pqnet any idea please?

Answer (score 2):

Server A lacks a route suggesting to connect to network `10.199.115.0/24` through VPN, thus uses its default route (i.e., try to reach B through your public IP).

Try to see if running

```
ip route add 10.199.115.0/24 via 10.1.1.2
```

on server A will allow connecting from A to B (without any NAT rule on firewall F)

If this works, you can set up openvpn to automatically create the route for you when you start the connection from A

## An explanation of what happens in your configuration.

Here it is how the routing/NAT happens in the three cases

### Case 1: B pings PUBLIC_IP

- The packet leaves B using the `default` route, because it is the only one that matches `PUBLIC_IP`. It is sent to be routed at the IP address `10.199.115.1`, with final destination `PUBLIC_IP`, and source address `10.199.115.146`.
- The packet is routed by F. Many routes apply: the most specific one is `PUBLIC_IP/32` which sends the packet to  be routed at the machine `10.0.2.2` on `eth0`, which I guess it is machine A (the connection underlying openvpn).
- Machine A receive the packet, and reply back to the source address `10.199.115.146`. Without the rule I showed you, this would be interpreted as an internet address, and thus the reply would be sent over the internet.
- using the route I proposed, the packet goes back through `tun0` to machine F. Machine F routes this back to `eth1` where machine B receives the reply packet.
  However, its source is marked as `10.1.1.1`, thus it is not recognized as the reply to the original packet. Ping failed.

### Case 2: B pings 10.1.1.1

- Same as before, the packet leaves B to be routed by F
- This time the destination matches the rule 10.1.1.1/32, so the packet is sent through `tun0`
- As the packet is going out through `tun0`, the `MASQUERADE` rule kicks in, changing the source for the packet as `10.1.1.2`. (this isn't needed if using the route rule I proposed, see below).
- Machine A receive the packet, and replies back to `10.1.1.2` (machine F). Without `MASQUERADE` this would be sent back to `10.199.115.146`. With my proposed routing table entry this wouldn't change much, because the package would be sent to `10.1.1.2` for routing nevertheless, however if you don't have either the destination `10.199.115.146` would be routed through internet.
- The reply packet is received by machine F. If masquerade was performed, the packet is recognized as reply and its destination address is changed back to `10.199.115.146`. The packet is routed through `eth1` to its final destination.
- Machine B recognize this as the reply packet. Ping successful.

### Case 3: A pings 10.199.115.146

- Without my proposed rule, the original packet is sent to the internet, and lost. Otherwise it is sent to `10.1.1.2` for routing, with source address = `10.1.1.1`.
- Machine F receives the packet and routes it through `eth1`.
- The packet is received by B and a reply is sent to `10.1.1.1`.
- The reply is routed through `tun0`. The `MASQUERADE` rule changes the source address to `10.1.1.2`.
- Machine A receives a reply from `10.1.1.2`, which is not the original destination, and discards it as unrelated. Ping failed

As you can see, there is 2 ways to connect machines from internal network to VPN:

- Public Routing: Both networks know each other's IP address, and they have specific route table entries to find them (as the one I showed you).
- SNAT/MASQUERADE: Only one network know how to reach the other, and the firewall changes the source IP address of outgoing packets from that network to the firewall's own IP (which is known by the other network).

Don't use both. If you use SNAT/MASQUERADE the routing tables on external hosts are not applicable because the packet coming from the private network are never using the original address as source.

You can choose whether machine A should be reachable from B using `PUBLIC_IP` or `10.1.1.1`. Maybe it is possible to configure the firewall such that both will work, but it is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks, so I add ip route add 10.199.115.0/24 via 10.1.1.2 to OpenVPN server (A) and I deleted rule -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.199.115.146 from firewall (F), but it still does not work... :-(

Comment: I added info about interfaces on all systems and iptables rules on VPN Server (A) and firewall (F) too.

Comment: @Mato you have a lot of strange routes on F. Can you explain where they come from (example: `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1`)?

Comment: @Mato I think the rule causing havoc is `-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE` on the firewall. You shouldn't need that if you are using the route I suggested  on A

Comment: @Mato also, A has another ethernet card with address 10.0.2.2 connected to `eth0` on F right?

Comment: Thank you. So in case 1 - ping failed, in case 2 ping is successful and in case 3 ping is successful too. Firewall (F) has ethernet card (interface) with IP 10.0.2.15 - I added it to main topick, but it is interface only for VBox NAT, I do not use it... So I have deleted -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE form Firewall and problem is still the same... :-(

Comment: I need use iptables, because I need redirect all ports except non-standard port for firewall SSH and except port 22 - SSH because there is special application (proxy), which records all activities and after redirect it to machine B. So I do not use only routing...

Comment: @Mato you deleted the firewall rule and added routing and it still doesn't work? Or you can ping A to B and at least one of B to A?

Comment: Yes I have deleted NAT rule -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE form Firewall (F) and I have added route on VPN Server (A) ip route add 10.199.115.0/24 via 10.1.1.2 like you said. Current state is in main post. HTTP does not work. (website which runs on machine B does not display via public IP) From A I can ping B(10.199.115.146), from B I can ping VPN IP of A - 10.1.1.1, but no MY_PUBLIC_IP and I can ping from B for example 8.8.8.8 too...

Comment: having A accessible both by MY_PUBLIC_IP and internal vpn ip is going to be troublesome. You shouldn't use MY_PUBLIC_IP to refer to your machines internally, especially since you have a virtual server. You can try to obtain that by adding `-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` on firewall. Note that you are masking on `eth0` instead of `tun0`

Comment: So, I have added iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE on Firewall, now ping to MY_PUBLIC_IP from B works correctly and others pings too, but HTTP still does not work :-(

Comment: I don't know about your HTTP server, this is the first time I heard of it. Where is it installed, where did you want to use it from, and what IP address are you using?

Comment: So, HTTP server which runs on machine B is Apache lastest version. Currently it runs on localhost of B machine or 10.199.115.146, in netstat -plntu it runs "on all interfaces/IP - ::80." Now I need access to this HTTP server via PUBLIC_IP from internet. And after when it will be works, I want run some other services similar way...

Comment: packets coming from the internet are DNATed to firewall machine. You need to DNAT them again from there to the webserver. For the physical machine to recognize that response packets are the same connection as the incoming packets, and thus be assigned the 80 outgoing port, you need to SNAT/MASQUERADE them from the firewall. That is, on F you add these two rules: `-t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.199.115.146` and `-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -p tcp -s 10.199.115.146 -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work :-( I added these iptables rules... I'm desperate...

Comment: where are you testing this from? I would expect it to work only from the outside of the network (or maybe from the physical machine).

Comment: I tested it from absolutly other PC from internet. I can send you other more detailed information too, but only private (because it is productive system for research) for example via mail or on IRC, IM etc...

Comment: @Mato I think this is the limit of my knowledge about complicated firewall and routing. At the moment I don't have a machine where I can experiment this configuration, in order to try to understand why it doesn't work, so I guess I wouldn't be able to help even if you told me more about your system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I do not know what do next :-( Please do you know about someone, who could know or about some specialized forum?